# Radio button does not redraw correctly

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Fig1:

[image: Fig1]

Fig2:

[image: Fig2]

As in Fig1, after I clicked radio button, the radio button seems not get correctly painted, seems 50% transparent.
As in Fig2, after I move my mouse to hover the radio button again, it got correctly painted.

I have no idea about what is going on behind.
What are the possible reasons?

By the way, after I pressed a shortcut key PrtSc to get a screenshot(a freeware: Greeshot), this problem disappeared.

---

One hint I just found is: the dialog holding the radios were in modeless mode. The problem disappeared after I showed it as a modal dialog.

Actually, to achieve below goals, I am implementing the message pump for this dialog. Perhaps I am doing something wrong in the message pump logic. Continue to check the pump.

My Goal: user can interact with other windows while showing this dialog, one exception is: user should not be able to interact with the parent dialog of this dialog in question, so that database transaction may be issued prematurally.

Comment: hi, can you provide [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure how to reproduce the problem in a new VC project.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have a similar problem within wxWidgets. Turns out it's a long lasting bug that really never had been fixed. I now use a workaround with a simple wrapper function that 'enables' the element (places focus on it) and then 'unfocuses' it. Not sure in your current setup.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this did not work for my situation..

Answer (score 0):

As a result, it seems I did something wrong in the message pump for the dialog in question.

> I am implementing the message pump for this dialog.

To avoid user interact with the parent dialog of the dialog in question, I was ignoring message for the parent dialog and to children of parent dialog.

After I changed the above logic to below, the problem got solved.
EnableWindow(hParent, FALSE);
EnableWindow(hParent, TRUE);

So, I think I was doing something wrong in ignoring message, not sure exactly where.

Comment: Why so complicated? Just make your dialog a *modal* dialog, and the system handles the rest for you, like disabling the owner window.

Comment: I need to disable the parent dialog, but also want user to be able to interact with grandparents etc. a modal dialog will disable all interactions beyond the dialog in question.

Comment: If that is how you want things to happen, then make sure to use [the correct order for disabling and enabling windows](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040227-00/?p=40463).